# How to get only hours and minutes

Tags: ios

I tried to extract hours,minute  from date but I am getting hours,minute and seconds. how to split the string.

```
NSArray *arr = [scheduling.scheduleFrom componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
NSString *schFromTime = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray *arrFrom = [schFromTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":00"];
NSString *timeFrom=[arrFrom  objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *arr2 = [scheduling.scheduleTo componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
NSString *schtoTime = [arr2 objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray *arrTo = [schtoTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSString *timeTo=[arrTo objectAtIndex:0];
ltimeslot.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@    %@",timeFrom,timeTo];
```

Comment: Google for NSDateFormatter class

Comment: provide your inputs and what you have implemented. given piece of code is useless.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your requirement ? OR can you put your JSON structure here??

Comment: can you show your date format and show what the output u need

Answer (score 3):

What do you really want? difference between two dates in hours and minutes? see this for

```
NSTimeInterval diff = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
NSString diffString = [self stringFromTimeInterval:diff];
```

`stringFromTimeInterval` function definition -

```
-(NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", (long)hours, (long)minutes];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components =
                    [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger second = [components second];
```